# Axis2 webservice deployment issue with Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, apache-axis, websphere-8

I am facing a trouble with axis2 webservices annotations. My environment is : WAS 8.5.5 , AXIS2 1.7 .

MyApplication had 5 services which need to be deployed in WAS and the client will consume. But, after deploying, i am getting lot of error in SystemOut.log mentioned below. I am a new bud to both Axis and Websphere. Kindly share your thoughts and help me in finding a solution for the same.  Please do let me know if u need ant files that need to look for more debug.

My main concern here is why i am getting null as below. Included in log below as well.

JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.DocServicesImpl as a service - nullDocServices

```
[1/30/15 3:55:14:983 PST] 00000001 OAuth20Provid I   CWOAU0001I: Initializing OAuth 20 providers.

 [1/30/15 3:55:15:155 PST] 00000040 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplication in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplication.

[1/30/15 3:55:15:483 PST] 00000040 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: MyApplication

[1/30/15 3:55:15:483 PST] 00000040 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: MyApplication  Application build level: Unknown

[1/30/15 3:55:17:311 PST] 00000040 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_81f191e4_15.01.30_03.55.17.1245101993067054092340.txt com.ibm.ws.websvcs.desc.WSModuleDescriptorImpl.buildServices 1362

[1/30/15 3:55:17:311 PST] 00000040 WSModuleDescr E   WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/apache/neethi/AssertionBuilderFactory.registerBuilder(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Lorg/apache/neethi/builders/AssertionBuilder;)V


[1/30/15 3:55:20:342 PST] 00000040 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer initialize SRVE0161I: IBM WebSphere Application Server - Web Container.  Copyright IBM Corp. 1998-2012
[1/30/15 3:55:20:342 PST] 00000040 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer initialize SRVE0162I: Servlet Specification Level: 3.0
[1/30/15 3:55:20:342 PST] 00000040 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer initialize SRVE0163I: Supported JSP Specification Level: 2.2

[1/30/15 3:55:20:452 PST] 00000040 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: MyApplication.war.

[1/30/15 3:55:20:733 PST] 00000040 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/myapplication

[1/30/15 3:55:37:780 PST] 00000040 AxisAdminServ W org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet init Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead

[1/30/15 3:55:37:811 PST] 00000040 ClusterBuilde I org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder buildCluster Clustering has been disabled

[1/30/15 3:55:38:749 PST] 00000040 JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.AppServicesImpl as a service - nullAppServices

[1/30/15 3:55:39:077 PST] 00000040 JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.DocServicesImpl as a service - nullDocServices

[1/30/15 3:55:39:342 PST] 00000040 ** JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.LibServicesImpl as a service - nullLibServices

[1/30/15 3:55:39:811 PST] 00000040 JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.QueueServicesImpl as a service - nullQueueServices

[1/30/15 3:55:40:014 PST] 00000040 JAXWSDeployer I org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport deployClasses Deploying JAXWS annotated class a.b.c.d.e.SysServicesImpl as a service - nullSysServices

[1/30/15 3:55:40:311 PST] 00000040 SystemOut     O Could not identify the Annotation....
[1/30/15 3:55:40:311 PST] 00000040 SystemOut     O Could not identify the Annotation....
[1/30/15 3:55:40:452 PST] 00000040 ServiceDeploy E org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer deploy The DocServices service, which is not valid, caused The following error occurred during schema generation:      sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl incompatible with java.lang.Class                               org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl incompatible with java.lang.Class 

 Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl incompatible with java.lang.Class at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)  .. 43 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl incompatible with java.lang.Class
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaForType(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:1062)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.processMethods(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:383)
at                                   org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchem    a(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:273)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:468)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388)
... 43 more
```

Comment: WebSphere is using Axis2 as web service engine, check [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwbs_faq.html?lang=en), so remove any Axis2 related Jars from your application libraries. Otherwise you will need to [disable JAX-WS engine](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-24-10-1&lang=en) in WAS

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur response. I have implemented your suggestion but I am getting  this error ---  WSWS7027E: JAX-WS Service Descriptions could not be correctly built because of the following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis2.modules.Module -- . I have removed my axis2 libraries from lib under WEB-INF and also from java classpath in WAS process Definition location. But still WAS is not able to load the AXIS2 jars itself. I dont want to disable JAXWS of WAS. So, i didnt opt that solution.

Comment: If you are using some specific Axis2 features it might not work that way. Check these 2 post how to use Axis2 in WebSphere [Axis2 config for WebSphere](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502240/module-is-not-valid-when-deploying-an-axis2-web-service-on-websphere

Answer (score 1):

1.Pls add Axis2 lib Jar path in to websphere console class path loader shared library location
2.Keep Axis2 lib Jar in to WAS lib(/usr/websphere/.... location.